# Método await queda tildado (Get web Api)

Tags: c#

Tengo una web api que devuelve un json equivalente a mi modelo, y funciona bien la web api, el problema es que no puedo leer el json porque queda parado el codigo en la linea del "await". La url que le envio es correcta también.

El codigo es este:

```
public static async Task<Datos> GetCallAPI(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datos>(response);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;



        }




        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string url = @"http://webapi.com/datos";

            Datos data = GetCallAPI(url).Result;

            label1.Text = data.Identificador;
            label2.Text = data.RazonSocial;
            label3.Text = data.NombreFantasia;

        }

    }

    public class Datos
    {
        public string Identificador { get; set; }
        public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

        public string NombreFantasia { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Define "queda parado", dar error o algo así? bueno quiza por que su llamado es async, el codigo continuara aunque aun no lleue el request, intenta ponerle un awaiter y result string response = client.GetStringAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: entiendo que lo vas a invocar por GET, si es asi, que pasa si pones la url en el browser ? porque lo hice y ademas de recibir un mensajes de "not found" me redirecciono a otra pagina. Quizas deberias evaluar que respuesta esperas conseguir

Comment: @JorgeFélixCazarez gracias por tratar de ayudar. sin embargo, por favor lee lo [siguiente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/324)

Comment: Esa web es de prueba nada mas, la original anda lo mas bien, no hay problema con eso. Devuelve el json bien. Pero desde el cliente en c# no logro hacer que devuelva los datos.

Comment: @JorgeFélixCazarez , no funciona ese codigo, me dice: "string does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter'

Comment: esto es .net o net.core?

Comment: .NET framework comun

Comment: Dale una revisada a [este código](https://github.com/lordoflies61/webapicall) hice un ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Listo, ya solucioné.

Me faltaba poner un "`async`" al evento `Click()` desde el cual estaba llamando al `async Task()`.

Muchas gracias!